# Re-sorting backbone collection from view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm having problems resorting my collection upon a click event. The sorting function is triggered and executes for each model but neither the reset event is gets triggered nor the collection changes on the view.

I have multiple sort criterias defined on my collection like:

```
feNoRequire.Collections.CompetitionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: feNoRequire.Models.CompetitionModel,
    comparator: function (property) {
        return selectedStrategy.apply(model.get(property));
    },
    strategies: {
        name: function (competition) { return competition.get("name"); }, 
        nameReverse: function (competition) { console.log(competition); return -competition.get("name"); }, 
        date: function (competition) { console.log(competition.get("event")); },
    },
    changeSort: function (sortProperty) {
        this.comparator = this.strategies[sortProperty];
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.changeSort("name");   
    }

});
```

And on my view file:

```
initialize: function(options){
        this.evnt = options.evnt;

        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);     
        this.evnt.bind("orderByDate", this.changeSort, this);
    },

    changeSort: function(){
        this.collection.changeSort('nameReverse')
        this.collection.sort();
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log("going for rendering")
        var renderedContent = this.template({competitions: this.collection.toJSON()});

        $(this.el).html(renderedContent);
        return this;
    }
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

**EDIT**
After the answers bellow the render is now triggered but the objected only get sorted on initialize. Any subsequent sorts return the collection in the initial order - this.changeSort("name");

my model:

```
feNoRequire.Models.CompetitionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.attributes.events = new feNoRequire.Collections.EventCollection(this.attributes.events);
    }
});
```

Comment: 'this.attributes.events = new feNoRequire.Collections.EventCollection(this.attributes.events);' <- out of curiousity, what's the purpose of this?

Comment: For each model, I have a list of events which I want to be models as well so I can sort them.

Comment: a late comment, for sure, but semantically, I would move the manual call to `this.collection.sort()` in the `View.changeSort` into the Collection's function, via `this.sort()`; this way you know when you call `changeSort()` on the collection, it will always re-sort itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort):

> **sort** `collection.sort([options])`
>
> [...] Calling sort triggers a `"sort"` event on the collection.

So calling `sort` doesn't trigger a `"reset"` event (because the collection doesn't get [`reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset)), it triggers a `"sort"` event. So you want to:

```
this.collection.on('sort', this.render, this);
```

as well as binding to `"reset"`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/34Ena/

---

I see that you're calling `changeSort('nameReverse')` and that that sorting does this:

```
nameReverse: function (competition) {
    return -competition.get("name");
}
```

That won't do what you think it does, negating a non-numeric string will give you `NaN`. That means that you'll end up trying to sort a list of `NaN`s and all of these are `false`:

```
NaN  < NaN
NaN  > NaN
NaN == NaN
```

so sorting a list of `NaN`s does nothing useful. You'll have to use a two argument comparator function if you want to reverse sort strings:

```
nameReverse: function(a, b) {
    a = a.get('name');
    b = b.get('name');
    return a < b ?  1
         : a > b ? -1
         :          0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is now triggering the render but the data isn't sorted. Any other ideas?

Comment: @jribeiro: Your `nameReverse` sorting doesn't do anything useful, negating a string gives you `NaN` rather than reversing the sort direction. Have a look at my update.

Comment: plus 1 for the nice fiddle :)

Comment: @muistooshort would it be better to use `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sort', this.render)` to prevent zombie views?

Comment: @AJP: Yes, I was only looking at the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You may listen to collection's `sort` event and perform render. Try changing event binding to:

```
this.collection.on('sort reset', this.render, this);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is now triggering the render but the data isn't sorted. Any other ideas?

Comment: `nameReverse` comparator is incorrect, check the answer of @mu.

Answer (score 1):

Very nice code setup.  I really like the way you're calling your sort functions via the strategies object.

I think the issue with this code is stemming from the following section:

```
comparator: function (property) {
    return selectedStrategy.apply(model.get(property));
},
```

as per the documentation, the comparator function takes a model or iterator (not a property), also not sure what selectedStrategy is supposed to be referencing... is this another function that exists somewhere outside the code you've provided?

Apply also takes a context object to act as "this", and an array of arguments.  As per the MDN documentation on apply:

```
fun.apply(thisArg[, argsArray])
```

unless your model's property is an object that you want to use as "this", i don't see this working properly.  Maybe it would make more sense if I could see the model definition as well.

**EDIT:** After reading the other responses that came in, I realized you're watching the reset event instead of the sort, so my response is probably just a misunderstanding of your code, and not the problem afterall :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes there might be some problem with the sorting but the first time round it works perfectly. Consequent calls don't really sort anything. Any idea?

Comment: @muistooshort is correct re: reverse string sorting.  I still see an issue with whatever it is you're doing in your comparator though.  It seems to me like you're using both comparator & apply wrong.  Take a look at Mu's fiddle.  Note that his comparator function takes a model as an argument (not a property).  Also take a look here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply - I've never seen any examples of apply being used the way you're using it.  Maybe if you could provide some more context I'd be able to comment further.